# How can I supply 5v voltage to circuit in a portable way?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, batteries, current, voltage-regulator

I have made a circuit which needs 5v to operate, I want to give 5v supply to that in portable and compact way. I didn't find any battery with 5v specs. I managed to run it with 9v battery in combination with 7805 voltage regulator but that battery is too heavy, bulky and I don't want to waste 9v for getting 5v only. Please let me know most compact and efficient way of supplying 5v voltage to a circuit.

P.S. Can I use 3v coin cell to run that circuit. Is there any way to step up from 3v coin battery to 5v?

Comment: Try a 'USB Power Bank'. These typically contain a single Li-Ion cell and a 5V boost converter.

Comment: @brhans, Will that be of less size than of 9v standard battery?

Comment: What is the current draw at 5 V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if it's really that important that this device be small and the batteries minimal, design it for 2.5-3.3 V power.  Then you can use a coin cell directly.  You will also find that most parts that run from this power voltage will draw less power than when running from 5 V.

Second, you can convert between voltages with a switching power supply.  However, these things will have some losss.  Right now you're getting (5 V)/(9 V) = 56% efficiency.  A small booster from a single AAA cell can do better than that, and the energy density of a typical AAA cell is better than of a typical 9 V battery.

However, it's difficult to make recommendations without knowing what the current demand is.  If it's 10 mA, then a coin cell isn't ever going to work, for example.

When designing for low power, you have to take the *whole design* into account, not just try to find the best power supply once other choices have been made that didn't consider low power.

Comment: Thanks @Olin Lathrop for pointing out those points and making me to think over **whole design** to consume minimal power instead of looking for best battery only. For what maximum current demand, 3v coin cell can be used? So that, I can try to redesign circuit to by keeping that objective in mind.

Comment: @Perry: Look at the datasheet of the coin cell you want to design for.  Average draw usually needs to be below 1 mA for capacity to not be degraded too much.  Short bursts can be higher, with sufficient capacitance across the battery helping with that.  Again, see the datasheet.

Comment: I am having a problem using ultrasonic sensors. Link to question is: [Link to question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214608/test-circuit-for-eu1640bch12t-r-water-proof-ultrasonic-sensors-with-arduino) Please help you know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

A portable USB power pack/brick provides a LIPO battery with 5V step-down charging and 5V step-up output in a convenient package. They can be found everywhere.

A 3V coin cell battery can be boosted to 5V, but a typical coin cell will last an hour or less like that, with any usable current draw.

Comment: Thanks @Passerby, Will that portable USB power pack/ brick be of less size than of 9v standard battery? Please give a reference if you can for this power brick.
P.S.- I want a small power source which I can package itself with PCB board.

Comment: Depends on how long you want to run the circuit with this supply. If you don't  want to run it for long time you can try the Power bank method. Although it won't fit in a PCB like you just said. BATTERY CELLS ARE BULKY.

Comment: @Perry some, yes. Most are bigger, but if you look around some can be quite small. I have one that's roughly 9v sized, solar powered, flashlight http://www.amazon.com/Bell-Howell-Solar-Charger/dp/B00941IFLW The bigger ones have bigger batteries and last longer.

Comment: @Perry I also have one of these super thin usb wallet batteries. http://www.midnightbox.com/mas_assets/alt2/10047745-110.jpg Again, the capacity is quite small, much better than a coin cell but probably on par with a 9V.