# Test circuit for EU1640BCH12T / R Water proof ultrasonic sensors with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, ultrasound, distance, test, waterproof

I have **EU1640BCH12T/R** waterproof ultrasonic sensors, which I have got from [this](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/16mm-waterproof-ultrasonic-type-distance-measuring-probe-sensor-transceiver-40KHz-1pair-lot/32377961028.html) link. These are standalone raw sensors without breakout board and not a module like **HC-SR04**. Being a new electronics hobbyist, I want to test these sensors with Arduino for distance sensing. I tried replacing transmitter and receiver of the original HC-SR04 module with my these ultrasonic ones but I am getting very ambiguous outputs from the circuit. Please suggest what circuit do I need to make to test these raw waterproof ultrasonic sensors?

Comment: Do you have a datasheet?

Comment: I asked seller for datasheet. He sent me this:
Model: EU1640BCH 
Diameter：16MM 
Nominal frequency ( KHz) : 40 KHz 
The emission sound pressure at 10V (0 db = 0.02 mPa) :≥110dB 
The receiving sensitivity at40KHz (0 db = V/ubar) : ≥-75dB Electrostatic capacity at1KHz, < 1 V(PF) : 1800±30%

Answer (score 1):

I think that either the transducer Q factor is too high for the board (extra inertia due to the metal case), causing a pulse to become abnormally long, or the transducers fail to efficiently couple acoustically with the air (impedance mismatch), causing a weak ultrasonic pulse and even weaker reception. Internally a transducer looks like this:

[image: ultrasonic transducer cutaway]

With the little horn being key to efficient coupling. At 40 kHz the wavelenght is just 330 m/s / 40 kHz = 8.25 mm.
Can you measure the terminals of the transmitter with an oscilloscope, and compare the results with the original transducer?

However I think that those transducers *should* work in open air with a proper controller as they are probably of the same design being used as parking sensors.

Designing an ultrasonic rangefinder is not a trivial task and is beyond the scope of a reasonable answer.